# My code in this batch file makes sense but it doesn't work properly

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have a little batch script that has two choices. It's kind of hard for me to explain this, just look at the code, it has comments and it will be easier to understand. Anyway, the script works properly only if I use the first choice. What's the deal?

```
echo Do you want to use arguments from the arguments text file? yes/no
set argumentstxt=+args.txt &:: This variable will contain the argument that tells the program to use arguments from the text file.
set /p answer=
if %answer% == yes goto :args
if %answer% == no goto :noargs
:noargs
set argumentstxt=-c 9999 &:: If I answered "no" then this line changes the first variable to do a different thing with the program. But if I answered yes then this line is completely ignored and the script goes to :args
:args
"C:\My program.exe" %argumentstxt%
exit
```

Comment: ***quote*** your `set` and `if` phrases. there is a `%= COMMENT =%` style that is more suitable in this condition. btw: Rule #1: **Never trust user input!** use delayed expansion

Comment: As you might have recognised, I removed the "(SOLVED)" prefix fro the title. Please use instead the ***green checkmark*** next to the answer that helped you most! Read [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how this works and why this is important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the built-in `choice` command for requesting known input.

For example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "argumentstxt=-c 9999"
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Do you want to use arguments from the arguments text file"
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Set "argumentstxt=+"args.txt""
"C:\My program.exe" %argumentstxt%
```

To read the command's usage information, in a Command Prompt window type `choice /?`, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

*Depending upon your circumstances, you may also wish to repeat the process using `start /?`. This would allow you to, for example, start your executable with the selected argument, and exit the script before waiting for the executable to complete*

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 echo Do you want to use arguments from the arguments text file? yes/no
set argumentstxt=+args.txt &:: This variable will contain the argument that tells the program to use arguments from the text file.
set /p answer=
if %answer% == yes goto :args
if %answer% == no goto :noargs
:noargs
set argumentstxt=-c 9999 &
exit
:args
"C:\My program.exe" %argumentstxt%
exit
```

Just put exit after no option. If you don't finish your app, it will move on to :args. So in your case if you choose no. It goes trough both options. If you choose yes, you only go trough "yes".

Comment: The ampersand in `set argumentstxt=-c 9999 &`must be removed; better write `set "argumentstxt=-c 9999"`. And you should use more quotes: `if "%answer%" == "yes"` to account for empty user input and to protect special characters; but this would still fail if someone would enter `&"&"`, for instance. To quit a batch file use `exit /B` rather than `exit`.